# Scope of members inside using statement

Tags: c#, using-statement

I'm confused by the following code and the scope of using statement and its object disposal.

```
using(DbFactory db = new DbFactory())
{
   Repository repo = new Repository<someobject>(db);
   result = repo.Get(somecondition);
}
```

In this code what happens after the using block execution will the `DbFactory` gets disposed?
What will be the scope of `repo` variable used inside the using statement?
The `DbFactory` is used by the `Repository` and it has a member variable which will hold the `DbFactory`.
So will this hold the disposal of `DbFactory`?

edit1:

```
Repository repo;
ResultObject result;
using(DbFactory db = new DbFactory())
{
   repo = new Repository<someobject>(db);
   result = repo.Get(somecondition);
}

public class Repository
{
    private _dbFactory;

    public Repository(DbFactory dbFactory)
    {
        _dbFactory = dbFactory;
    }
}
```

Now will the DbFactory gets disposed after the using statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scope of the `repo` variable (in your first case) is the `using` statement. You can't refer to it outside the `using` statement, because it's declared in there.

We can't tell the scope of the `result` variable because you haven't shown its declaration, but it's at least "bigger than the `using` statement".

What's more interesting is how usable the object that the value of `result` refers to is after the `DbFactory` has been disposed. That's implementation-specific, basically... I'd expect that if accessing any `result` properties requires further database queries (e.g. to get an object referenced by foreign key) then it would fail, but anything that's already fetched should be fine.

As for the timing of disposal - the `DbFactory` will be disposed at the end of the `using` statement. That's entirely separate from garbage collection, and presumably the `Repository` object will still have a reference to it - but it's likely to be useless after the factory has been disposed. So if you call `repo.Get(...)` *after* the `using` statement, you'll probably see an exception, depending on what that code actually does with the factory, and how a disposed factory behaves. Again, *disposal isn't garbage collection*. It's just calling the `Dispose` method - the CLR doesn't care about that in any special way.

Comment: Edited the question. I'm confused that will the repo variable holds disposal of DbContext after the using statement or DbContext disposed right after using statement and the repo will wait for gc?

Comment: Dispose hasn't anything to do with GarbageCollector as Dispose method isn't destructor and so the GC will not be called just when Dispose method is.

Comment: @jonskeet Great point, I'm looking for that timing of disposal.

Answer (score 3):

> will the DbFactory gets disposed?

Yes.

> What will be the scope of repo variable used inside the using statement?

The scope of `repo` is the block that it is contained in, so the pair of curly braces ('{', '}') that it's wrapped in.  In this case, it happens to coincide with the body of your `using` statement, yes.

Comment: So the `repo` variable won't hold disposal of `DbFactory` right?

Comment: @Rebornx It holds onto the same object, so if that object is disposed, and the repository tries to use an operation that isn't supported on a disposed object, then it won't function.

Answer (score 0):

If the repo is also disposable you may want to dispose it also, for exampe:

```
using(DbFactory db = new DbFactory())
using(Repository repo = new Repository<someobject>(db))
{
   result = repo.Get(somecondition);
}
```

Comment: I know that. But is it good pattern to make the Repository as disposable?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Repository repo;
ResultObject result;
using(DbFactory db = new DbFactory())
{
   repo = new Repository<someobject>(db);
   result = repo.Get(somecondition);
}
```

Is same as this one:

```
Repository repo;
ResultObject result;
{
    DbFactory db = new DbFactory()
    repo = new Repository<someobject>(db);
    result = repo.Get(somecondition);
    db.Dispose();
}
```

So though the db object itself won't wanish (reference to it will be keept in Repository instance, it will be in Disposed/Closed state. Depending on implementation of DbFactory that probably will break your code.

You didn't provide full code and what it should do but I think you should go in this direction:

1. Implement IDisposable in your Repository object and inside it dispose DbFactory as well:

   ```
   public class Repository : IDisposable
   {
       private _dbFactory;

       public Repository(DbFactory dbFactory)
       {
           _dbFactory = dbFactory;
       }

       public void Dispose()
       {
           _dbFactory.Dispose();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now use it like so:

   ```
   ResultObject result;
   using (Repository repo = new Repository(new DbFactory())
   {
       result = repo.Get(somecondition);
   }
   ```

Or use nested using:

```
using (DbFactory db = new DbFactory())
{
    using(Repository repo = new Repository(db))
    {
        result = repo.Get(somecondition);
    }
}
```